# Add total label ChartWrapper Google Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

How can I add total label on each column to ChartWrapper google chart?
I tryed to search into documentation from google charts, but I'm new in google chart and is not so easy for me.

The link of image below it's a example I want. 
[example I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTDOq.jpg)

Follow my code below, it's a simple code.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {
            callback: drawChart_var,
            packages: ['corechart']
        });
        function drawChart_var() {
            var dataChart = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
                [[{ label: 'Category', type: 'string' },{ label: '', type: 'number' },
                { label: 'Base 2', type: 'number' },{ label: 'Base 3', type: 'number' },
                { label: 'Base 4', type: 'number' },{ role: 'style', type: 'string', p: { role: 'style' } }],
                ['VAR', 0, 0, 3.42, 0, '#EEB14C'],['MIX', 0, 3.42, 3.73, 0, '#69AA51'],
                ['BNS', 0, 3.73, 3.42, 0, '#D53C38'],['MTRL', 0, 3.42, 2.34, 0, '#D53C38'],
                ['OTHER', 0, 2.34, 2.69, 0, '#69AA51'],['CORP', 0, 2.69, 0.7, 0, '#D53C38'],
                ['COST', 0, 0.7, 1.94, 0, '#69AA51'],['PNL', 0, 1.94, 0, 0, '#EEB14C']]
            );
            var options = {
                animation: {duration: 1500,easing: 'inAndOut',startup: true},
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',bar: {group: {width: '85%'}},
                chartArea: {left: 50,right: 20,bottom: 60,top: 50,width: "100%",height: "70%"},
                hAxis: {textStyle: {fontSize: 12}},
                height: 400,
                legend: 'none',
                seriesType: 'bars',
                series: {0: {type: 'candlesticks'}},
                tooltip: {isHtml: true,trigger: 'both'},
                vAxis: {format: 'short',textStyle: {color: '#616161'},viewWindow: {min: 0,max: 11}},
                width: '100%',
                annotations: {stem: {color: "transparent",length: 100},
                textStyle: {color: "#000000",fontSize: 16,}}
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();
            chart.setChartType('ComboChart');
            chart.setDataTable(dataChart);
            chart.setContainerId('chart_var');
            chart.setOptions(options);
            chart.draw();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_var"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add labels above the bars, you can use an [annotation column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#annotationrole).

```
{ role: 'annotation', type: 'string' }
```

however, in this case, candle stick series do not support annotations.
you can check which roles are supported by reviewing the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart#data-format) for each chart type.

as such, we need to add a second bar series, then add the annotation column.

```
{ label: 'bar series', type: 'number' },{ role: 'annotation', type: 'string' }
```

see following working example, for the bar series, we just use a value of zero...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart_var,
  packages: ['corechart']
});
function drawChart_var() {
  var dataChart = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    [[{ label: 'Category', type: 'string' },{ label: '', type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Base 2', type: 'number' },{ label: 'Base 3', type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Base 4', type: 'number' },{ role: 'style', type: 'string', p: { role: 'style' } },
    { label: 'bar series', type: 'number' },{ role: 'annotation', type: 'string' }],
    ['VAR', 0, 0, 3.42, 0, '#EEB14C', 0, '3.42'],['MIX', 0, 3.42, 3.73, 0, '#69AA51', 0, '0.31'],
    ['BNS', 0, 3.73, 3.42, 0, '#D53C38', 0, '-0.31'],['MTRL', 0, 3.42, 2.34, 0, '#D53C38', 0, '-1.08'],
    ['OTHER', 0, 2.34, 2.69, 0, '#69AA51', 0, '0.35'],['CORP', 0, 2.69, 0.7, 0, '#D53C38', 0, '-1.99'],
    ['COST', 0, 0.7, 1.94, 0, '#69AA51', 0, '1.24'],['PNL', 0, 1.94, 0, 0, '#EEB14C', 0, '1.94']]
  );
  
  var options = {
    animation: {duration: 1500,easing: 'inAndOut',startup: true},
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',bar: {group: {width: '85%'}},
    chartArea: {left: 50,right: 20,bottom: 60,top: 50,width: "100%",height: "70%"},
    hAxis: {textStyle: {fontSize: 12}},
    height: 400,
    legend: 'none',
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {0: {type: 'candlesticks'}},
    tooltip: {isHtml: true,trigger: 'both'},
    vAxis: {format: 'short',textStyle: {color: '#616161'},viewWindow: {min: 0,max: 11}},
    width: '100%',
    annotations: {stem: {color: "transparent",length: 100},
    textStyle: {color: "#000000",fontSize: 16,}}
  };
 
  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();
  chart.setChartType('ComboChart');
  chart.setDataTable(dataChart);
  chart.setContainerId('chart_var');
  chart.setOptions(options);
  chart.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_var"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

as for the position of the annotation.
given we are using a value of zero for the column the annotation is for,
the position is being set by option --> `annotations.stem.length = 100`
meaning it will always be 100 pixels from the bottom of the chart.

to make the position dynamic, we need to remove the `length` option,
and give the column a value greater than zero.
the column value should be the max value of the candlesticks.

to find the max value, we can use data table method --> `getColumnRange(colIndex)`
this method will return an object with properties for the min & max values of the column we provide.

we need to find the max between the Base 2 and Base 3 columns.

```
// find max height
var maxBase2 = dataChart.getColumnRange(2);
var maxBase3 = dataChart.getColumnRange(3);
var maxColumn = Math.max(maxBase2.max, maxBase3.max);
```

then update our annotation column with the max value.

```
// update column values to max
for (var i = 0; i < dataChart.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  dataChart.setValue(i, 6, maxColumn);
}
```

to ensure the annotation displays on top of the column,
add option --> `alwaysOutside`

```
annotations: {
  alwaysOutside: true,
  stem: {color: 'transparent'},
  textStyle: {color: '#000000',fontSize: 16}
}
```

again, remove the `length` option.

and also set the color of the column series to transparent.

```
  1: {color: 'transparent'}
```

this will cause the annotation to always appear just above the candlesticks.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart_var,
  packages: ['corechart']
});
function drawChart_var() {

  var dataChart = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    [[{ label: 'Category', type: 'string' },{ label: '', type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Base 2', type: 'number' },{ label: 'Base 3', type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Base 4', type: 'number' },{ role: 'style', type: 'string', p: { role: 'style' } },
    { label: 'bar series', type: 'number' },{ role: 'annotation', type: 'string' }],
    ['VAR', 0, 0, 3.42, 0, '#EEB14C', 0, '3.42'],['MIX', 0, 3.42, 3.73, 0, '#69AA51', 0, '0.31'],
    ['BNS', 0, 3.73, 3.42, 0, '#D53C38', 0, '-0.31'],['MTRL', 0, 3.42, 2.34, 0, '#D53C38', 0, '-1.08'],
    ['OTHER', 0, 2.34, 2.69, 0, '#69AA51', 0, '0.35'],['CORP', 0, 2.69, 0.7, 0, '#D53C38', 0, '-1.99'],
    ['COST', 0, 0.7, 1.94, 0, '#69AA51', 0, '1.24'],['PNL', 0, 1.94, 0, 0, '#EEB14C', 0, '1.94']]
  );

    // find max height
    var maxBase2 = dataChart.getColumnRange(2);
    var maxBase3 = dataChart.getColumnRange(3);
    var maxColumn = Math.max(maxBase2.max, maxBase3.max);

    // update column values to max
    for (var i = 0; i < dataChart.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      dataChart.setValue(i, 6, maxColumn);
    }

  var options = {
    animation: {duration: 1500,easing: 'inAndOut',startup: true},
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',bar: {group: {width: '85%'}},
    chartArea: {left: 50,right: 20,bottom: 60,top: 50,width: '100%',height: '70%'},
    hAxis: {textStyle: {fontSize: 12}},
    height: 400,
    legend: 'none',
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
      0: {type: 'candlesticks'},
      1: {color: 'transparent'}
    },
    tooltip: {isHtml: true,trigger: 'both'},
    vAxis: {format: 'short',textStyle: {color: '#616161'},viewWindow: {min: 0,max: 11}},
    width: '100%',
    annotations: {
      alwaysOutside: true,
      stem: {color: 'transparent'},
      textStyle: {color: '#000000',fontSize: 16}
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();
  chart.setChartType('ComboChart');
  chart.setDataTable(dataChart);
  chart.setContainerId('chart_var');
  chart.setOptions(options);
  chart.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_var"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work, but, it's possible make the position flexible.

Comment: sorry, was a question!